# Once data is loaded from database, dont want to send again database call on switching tabs in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Problem Statement:
I am using angular js. if i load one tab, my database calls returns some tables and graphs data. then i move to next tab, now if i come back on my first tab, database call will again goes to database. i want to stop these database calls once data is loaded with one parameter, then it should remain loaded till param is changed.

i am using angular js and its routing to switch tabs.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/daily',
{
 title: 'Daily - Stats',
 templateUrl: '/SPA/Daily.html'
}).when
```

Kindly suggest me some solution, as i am new to AngularJS

Comment: You can check the value of variable where you put the response from database, if data is there then you can return your function before call to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following approach

```
    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/daily',
        {
        title: 'Daily - Stats',
        templateUrl: '/SPA/Daily.html',
        resolve:{
                //code to load the it from database use a FACTORY
                //getgraphDetails  call the serviceName.getgraphDetails

        }
        })
    });
```

**Define two factory as below one for the appVariables and the other one for all your web service call**

```
    myApp.factory('appVariables', function appVariablesFactory() {
        var graphDetails=[];
        return {
                    graphDetails:graphDetails

            }
    });

        myApp.factory('serviceName', function serviceNameFactory(appVariables) {
            return {
                    //have your http call here 
                    getgraphDetails :function()
                    {
                     if(appVariables.graphDetails!=null||appVariables.graphDetails!=undefined);
                     { 
                      //raise the api call to get the details
                     }
            }

        });
```

Not able to give the complete code because your service calls are not available in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Use a service that call API only once and then store data:

```
app.service('MyService', function() {
    this.getData = function() {
        if(this.data === undefined || this.data === null) {
            //Call your API and store result in this.data
        }
        return this.data;
    };        
});
```

You can now [inject](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) this service in your controller and call `MyService.getData()`.